# Multivariate normal density function in C++

Tags: c++, distribution, gaussian

How can I calculate the [multivariate normal density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) in C++ (for an arbitrary dimension) in a numerically stable way, and ideally with minimum number of dependencies?

To be precise I am after the logarithm of the density.

Comment: What is "numerically stable way" and "minimum number of dependencies"? Because, for example, -"The precise definition of stability depends on the context, but it is derived from the accuracy of the algorithm." If you clarify the requirements there will be less wrong suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would have calculated using the formula for Normal Distribution.  Did you try that?

Comment: You do realize that the integral for normal distribution is unsolveable and is only approximated using numerical methods?

Comment: @amit: Why do you need to integrate it?

Comment: yeah he's looking for PDF not CDF.  I don't think there is a need to integrate...  just evaluate it.

Comment: @amit, there is no integral in the formula for the density (there is in the cdf). There is a determinant and inverse of the covariation matrix. I don't think there is anything readily available in boost to calculate these. Moreover, using the formula directly as it is might be numerically unstable.

Comment: Sorry did not read the question properly.  It is multivariate NDF.  I don't know.

Comment: are you having cases where there may be correlations between the variables?

Comment: @thang, yes, there might be correlation. Basically the covariance matrix captures all this. I need to make it generic (unfortunately).

Comment: you may want to look into the root library (http://root.cern.ch/).  specifically, look at http://root.cern.ch/root/html/RooNDKeysPdf.html.  Probably does more than you want and maybe not even what you want, but it's worth a shot.  I haven't used root in a long time.